# Passing Json Dates to an action method in mvc

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

The following code is deployed to azure:

javascript:

```
    var _dp;

    $(function () {
        kendo.culture("en-GB");
        _dp = $("#modified").kendoDatePicker().data("kendoDatePicker");
    });

    function postData() {
        var data = {
            Modified: _dp.value()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "/location/edit",
            success: function (response) {
                log(response.modifedLocalDateTime);
                log(response.modifiedLocalKind);
                log(response.modifiedUtcDateTime);
                log(response.modifiedUtcKind);
            }
        });
    }

    function log(msg) {
        document.getElementById('divLog').innerHTML += "<br/>" + msg;
    }
```

My html is

```
<input type="text" id="modified" />

<a href="javascript:postData();">postData</a>

<div id="divLog"></div>
```

My mvc controller is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(LocationViewModel item)
    {
        var modifiedUtc = item.Modified;
        var modifiedLocal = modifiedUtc.ToLocalTime();

        return Json(new
        {
            modifedLocalDateTime = modifiedLocal.ToString(),
            modifiedLocalKind = modifiedLocal.Kind.ToString(),
            modifiedUtcDateTime = modifiedUtc.ToString(),
            modifiedUtcKind = modifiedUtc.Kind.ToString()
        });
    }

public class LocationViewModel
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
}
```

Also worth pointing out that I have in my webapi.config:

```
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

Now I pick a date using the kendo date picker say 29 May 2015 and click the post data. What I get back is 1 hour earlier that what I asked for. Not quite what I was expecting. My region is UK, so we are in British summer time which is UTC + 1.

So I was expecting dates to be transferred as UTC - looking at fiddler this seems to be so:

[image]

So Web api should receive a date in utc format. However looking at the output, web api, receives 28 May 2015 23:00, with the kind property set to local? Why is the kind property set to utc - which I would expect), as in my webapi.config I specified UTC... So why is this?

What I currently get is this

[image]

What I want is to receive 29 May 2015 and not 28 May 2015 23:00 in my action method.

How can I do this?

Comment: From my understanding, sending a date over any type of webservice will be converted to w.e the server timezone is.  So, I would send the date as string back to the server

Answer (score 0):

You're passing to the server the [Zulu time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z), i.e. the UTC, without any offset. The server is converting it to its own time zone. So you can solve the problem in two ways:

- correct the client, so that it sends the right offset to the server
- send the date from the clientwithout offset, so that it doesn't make any changes on it

For the second option, you can use the ISO format, which looks like this:

```
2015-05-17T13:32:00 // YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ddddd
```

This format is always interpreted as expected, and, as there is no time zone specified, the date is left as is in the server.

You could use moment.js to hlep you manipulate dates before sending them back to the server.